# Libnet basic use

Tags: c, macos, gcc, libnet

I have been looking over the example source provided with libnet, however, I am unclear on what to do with the following.

```
length+=LIBNET_TCP_H;
t = libnet_build_tcp(
    0x6666,                                     /* source port */
    179,                                        /* destination port */
    0x01010101,                                 /* sequence number */
    0x02020202,                                 /* acknowledgement num */
    TH_SYN,                                     /* control flags */
    32767,                                      /* window size */
    0,                                          /* checksum */
    0,                                          /* urgent pointer */
length,                                     /* TCP packet size */
    NULL,                                       /* payload */
    0,                                          /* payload size */
    l,                                          /* libnet handle */
    0);                                         /* libnet id */
```

This a appears to be a tcp header construction, however, if I want to change the dst port do I do it at the # 179, or is there a better way?

Also, is this the correct way to compile:

gcc -Wall `libnet-config --defines` arp-new-new.c `libnet-config --libs` -lpcap -lnet

Answer (score 0):

In my little experience of libnet, the field where you have the dst port is that where was 179, and my own compilation command is : $ gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -pedantic disect5.c -lpcap `libnet-config --defines` `libnet-config --libs` -lnet -o disect5
 (for a C program named disect5)
gretz